# JSON object returned but not accessible via $.ajax()

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, jquery

I have an ASP.NET MVC Web API that I am calling from an $.ajax() method. The correct JSON is returned from my API, but the object is not accessible. The error received in my console when trying to log the value for "Name" is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Name' of undefined

JSON:

```
[{"id":2,"Name":"thom","Picture":"thom.jpg","About":"I'm a guy. This is my profile. Now quit staring and get out of here.","Location":"London"}]
```

jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
            cache:false,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'http://localhost:3235/Users/searchUsers?callback=?&searchString=' + searchString,
            complete: function (data) {
                console.log(data[0].Name);
            }
        });
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Try logging what `data` is.

Comment: Can you show what logs if you simply `console.log(data)` to see what is returning, rather than just knowing `Name` is not there

Comment: You are probably returning the result with a `content-type` of `text/html`. Either `JSON.stringify(result)` in JS or send the correct headers with the response.

Comment: Even if header is wrong, it would not matter if he is specifying that it is json.

Comment: jQuery automatically parses it for you when you include `dataType:"json"` as is being done in the code above.

Comment: ColinDeClue + @DaveStein data logs as 'Object {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}'

Comment: Makes sense considering Jim's and Alvaro's answers. Just gotta pick which you like better and mark this one as solved.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you mean to use the `success` function. The `complete` function doesn't take `data` as a parameter.

Comment: I can't believe I didn't notice that too :P

Comment: +1. I can't believe as well. Was thinking that squint solved it :D

Comment: @Ejay: Yeah, I totally missed the boat on that one. Didn't even consider the callback type. Though I wonder if the issue in Yatrix's answer will come into play too.

Comment: Success hadn't been working, but it's magically working again. Good to know that 'complete' doesn't take data. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 4):

From [the docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> **complete**
> Type: Function( **jqXHR jqXHR**, String textStatus )
> A function
>   to be called when the request finishes (after success and error
>   callbacks are executed). The function gets passed two arguments: The
>   jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHTTPRequest) object and a string
>   categorizing the status of the request ("success", "notmodified",
>   "error", "timeout", "abort", or "parsererror").

The method's first parameter is *not* the received data. You can get it though the `jqXHR` object but I don't think you really need to use this option. Use `success` instead:

> **success**
>  Type: Function( **PlainObject data**, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR )
>  A function to be called if the request
>   succeeds. The function gets passed three arguments: The data returned
>   from the server, formatted according to the dataType parameter; a
>   string describing the status; and the jqXHR (in jQuery 1.4.x,
>   XMLHttpRequest) object.

Answer (score 1):

ya complete fires after the service call is being made and it does not contain data from the service response..

use

```
$.ajax({
url:'ur url',
type:'GET'
success:function(data){
// way to acces ur object code goes here


console.log(data[0].Name);


},
error:function(){
// Error handling
}
});
```

happy coding